# How to included php file in html so the website loads where the php starts and not at the beginning?

Tags: php, html, include

I programmed a Website in html, css and JavaScript. I decided to put a contact form directly into my front page and use the "include" comand to include my php.file

```
(<?php include ("form_process.php";?>)
```

after that I have the html code for the form itself

```
(form id="content" action="< ?= $SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> ...)
```

Everything works well, I can receive e-mails etc, the website is displayed as it should be. However, it loads first at the point in the html script where the php file is included. 
This means: if you go on the page you see the contact form first (which is at the end) and then you can scroll at the top... 
I know that the server executes php first and then displays the static html stuff. However is there any solution that the visitor could see the header first when visiting my website?

Comment: soo the page scrolls down to the form or the form is on the top of the page?

Comment: If you could provide an example of the problem that would really help us understand what you're trying to describe.

Comment: It sounds like you are adding an id (like `#some_id`) to the end of the url and the browser scrolls to that id as it exists in the page.

Comment: Did you put the include() at or near the top of the main file?

Comment: The form is on the bottom of the page and when you type in the url it loads first at this bottom contact form. The form is the only php in the script. The idea with the id was smart but my url does not include this id. 
I put the include() near at the main file. But actually I tried it to put it close to the top and it did not change anything...

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <title>website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
 </head>
 <body class="is-preload">
  <!-- Wrapper -->
   <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Intro -->
     <section class="intro">
      ...
     <section>
    < form id="contact" action="form_process.php" method="post"> 
        <div class="fields">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?= $name ?>" autofocus/>
                                        <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
         </div></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use include

```
<form id="content" method="post" action="form_process.php">...</form>
```

Use this on post

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Again the side loads first at the contact form